# Saving files as CSV using loops in R

Tags: r, loops, csv, saving-data

I have a set of codes I want to run on multiple files to do this I used the following loop

```
setwd("~/folderofinterest")
cluster <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv$")
for(i in 1:length(cluster)){
```

here is where I put in my code that results in a dataset called "countedclusters"
then I add this to try and save the files as they are created but still retain the names of the original files

```
setwd("~/folderofinterest/done")
write.csv (countedclusters, file=cluster[i], quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
setwd("~/Desktop/cluster/")
}
```

instead of saving the files into the "done" folder I get this error:

> Error in if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file))
>   { :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

not sure what I am doing wrong, any help would be great, thx

Here is an update with example code (my actual code is to long)

```
setwd("~/Desktop/folderofinterest/")
cluster <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv$")
for(i in 1:length(cluster)){
DS1 <- read.csv(file = cluster[i], header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
X=1
Y=2
for(i in 1:100){
Y=X+Y
}
DS1$newcolumn<-Y
countedclusters<-DS1
setwd("~/Desktop/folderofinterest/done")
write.csv (countedclusters, file=cluster[i], quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
setwd("~/Desktop/folderofinterest/")
}
```

what should happen is that I get files (named based on original files names found in folderofInterest) saved in done folder with a new column called "newcolumn with a value of "102"

instead I get this error:

> Error in if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file))
>   { :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: Why all these `setwd`? Also, what is `countedclusters`?

Comment: I guess your `list.files()` returns `NA`, i.e. it is empty

Comment: I tested your list.files in a folder with some .csv files in it and it worked. I can't test much else though, given the code above. Make sure there are .csv files in the folder referenced.

Comment: @Fernando i use the setwd to grab and save the data sets that are located in different location (different folders/places of server) the countedclusters is a new dataset that is created from the loop from data extracted from the different cluster files, (I didnt not add that code because it is working). I hope that makes sense

Comment: `Error in if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` is exactly the error you get when `write.csv(.., file=NA)`. Have you checked that?

Comment: What's the output of `print(cluster)?`

Comment: @SimonDirmeier when 'list.files()' is used it does return files, also if i change it to 'write.csv(.., file=NA)' it gives me the same error.  One thing I did not metion is that nested in the entire code there are other loops to repeat codes i.e. 'for(i in 1:100){....}' that way it repeats a function 100 times, could that be causing the error?

Comment: @Fernando the output of print(cluster) returns the list of files in "folderofinterest" same as if you did 'list.files'

Comment: @StevenL So you should post the entire code. Something is messing the filename.

Comment: @Fernando, i updated the question with example code, thx

Comment: I think your issue is that you have a for loop using `i` as the index nested inside a for loop **also using `i` as the index**. After the inner loop, `i` will be 100 and `cluster[100]` doesn't exist so it will return `NA`. Use a different index variable for your inner `for` loop. Recommend to close the question as typo.

Comment: @Gregor, thanks that was the issue

Comment: This is a good reason to make a habit of using meaningful variable names even in `for` loop indexes. You could re-write to make it something like `for (cluster in cluster_csv)` for the outer loop and maybe there's something equally meaningful for the inner loop.

Comment: Also, learn to indent your code!